# SQL: converting datetime from character string when inserting date

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures, type-conversion

I have the following procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedute]
    @mydate VARCHAR(8000) = NULL

IF @mydate = ''
        BEGIN
            SET @mydate = NULL
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
        SET @mydate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @mydate, 103) -- dd/mm/yy
        END

    INSERT INTO  dbo.myTable(theDate) VALUES(@mydate)
```

And I execute it like this:

```
EXEC  [dbo].[myProcedure] '02/02/2012'
```

After execution I get this error: 
Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

I execute it from my vb6 code and the date can vary. This time is 
'02/02/2012' but next time it may be ''(empty).

When it comes as '',  I need it to insert a NULL as you can see in the IF clause.

Why am I getting this error?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: why don't you change the definition `@mydate` to `DATE` ?

Comment: try

    IF LTRIM(@mydate) = ''

Comment: I suggest to TO_DATE(LTRIM(@mydate),'DD/MM/YY')

Comment: Passing it as a `datetime` would save a lot of issues.

Comment: @Luv - VB6 means ADO classic, which I don't think ever got updated for the 2008 types.

Comment: [Seems](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8035) conversion is fine. It must be something else. And this is MS SQL Server right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ISDATE() to check if it is a valid date.

Conversion seems fine. And as comments suggests, it would solve a lot if you could change parameter to `DATE`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedute]
    @mydate VARCHAR(8000) = NULL

IF ISDATE(@mydate)
    BEGIN
        SET @mydate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @mydate, 103) -- dd/mm/yy
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SET @mydate = NULL        
    END

INSERT INTO  dbo.myTable(theDate) VALUES(@mydate)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to format your date string to ***ISO format*** (`yyyymmdd`) which guaranteed to work on any sql-server. Assuming you vb code passing it like `dd/mm/yyyy` (as per your data). Try this;

```
--Format @mydate to yyyymmdd
SELECT @mydate = CASE LEN(@mydate) WHEN 10 
         THEN RIGHT(@mydate,4)+ SUBSTRING(@mydate,4,2)+ LEFT(@mydate,2)
         ELSE NULL END
--Insert
INSERT INTO  dbo.myTable(theDate) VALUES(@mydate)
```